# Help Find A Sequence With The Property s(i) < s(i+1) XOR s(i+1) < s(i+2)

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm looking for a sequence of positive integers with the property that, where $s(i)$ denotes the $i$th term, $s(i)<s(i+1)$ or $s(i+1)<s(i+2)$ but not both. The sequence also has the property that $s(i)=s(j)$ iff $i=j$. An OEIS number would be ideal.

Comment: Must it satisfy the requirement for all i? If so, that may be a bit hard to get: s(i)<s(i+1) for all i implies that for j=i+1 we have s(i+1)=s(j)<s(j+1)=s(i+2).

Comment: I would also be interested in showing that such a sequence is impossible to construct. But, you are right, it is not necessary that s(i)<s(i+1) for all i as that would imply s(i+1) < s(i+2). It would only be true for some i.

Comment: What about this sequence: $1,3,2,5,4,7,6,9,8,11,10,13,12,...$

Comment: That works really well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many such sequences; you merely have that it alternates increasing a decreasing and is injective. The example
$$s(n)=n-(-1)^n$$
which starts $2,1,4,3,6,5,\ldots$ satisfies this.

Comment: I forgot to add the constraint that I was looking for a sequence of positive integers. I've edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: @Peter Added another example.